# IIS 7 Default document not loading on subdirectory

Tags: iis-7.5, subdomain, default-document

I have a subdomain pointed at my server and in IIS 7.5 have a site set up for it which works fine.

If I navigate to http://test.example.com the default index.php page loads as it should.

I also have a sub-section of the site located at http://test.example.com/viewer

This also has a default index.php page, however when I navigate to that URL, I get a 404 error. Entering the full path to the index file (i.e. .../index.php) loads fine.

I have checked the default document for both the root and the subdirectory, and they are the same.

Any ideas how to get the default document in the subdirectory loading?

Comment: Have you checked IIS logs for that site? As well event viewer might shed some light.

Comment: i have just checked the log file and instead of logging the request as "GET /viewer/" as one would expect, it is logging the request as "GET /view.php id=viewer"

Comment: Have you validated that permissions on both folders are the same? As well, who's defined as the IIS user? Anonymous?